# Limit area of screen to UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipangesturerecognizer

I have 3 UIViews that change their height as my finger moves up and down the screen, each like this:

```
- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)aPan; {
    CGPoint currentPoint = [aPan locationInView:self.view];

    currentPoint.y -= 80;

    if (currentPoint.y < 0) {
        currentPoint.y = 0;
    }
    else if (currentPoint.y > 240) {
        currentPoint.y = 240;
    }

    currentPoint.y = 240.0 - currentPoint.y;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.01f
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect oldFrame = secondBar.frame;
                         secondBar.frame = CGRectMake(oldFrame.origin.x, (oldFrame.origin.y - (currentPoint.y - secondBar.frame.size.height)), oldFrame.size.width, (currentPoint.y));
                     }];
}
```

However, moving my finger on the screen moves all three views. How can I change it so that when my finger is over a certain part of the screen/over a particular view, it only moves that view?